# PDF form get checkbox group value

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf

I have a PDF form with a number of checkboxes with the same field name.  The user can only select one of the items form the list of checkboxes, and they must be able to uncheck the checkbox too.

I want to get the value of the checked checkbox and use it to populate the value of another field.

My calculation script works in Adobe Acrobat but in browsers (Edge/Chrome) the script only retrieves the first field from the group of checkboxes.  This is my script:

```
var Membership_Type = this.getField("Membership_Type").valueAsString;
var price = 0;

switch(Membership_Type) {
    case "Family":
        price = 50;
        break;
    case "Couple":
        price = 30;
        break;
    case "Individual":
        price = 20;
        break;
}

event.value = price;
```

An example of the problem can be seen here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NZqXROEvFXm279bZ3pdcHNydnUbv1gFv/view?usp=sharing

Is there any way to make this work in all PDF viewers?

Answer (score 0):

Every browser with a PDF extender has different abilities so your Adobe Scripting requires an "Acrobat Compatible Reader" Such as FireFox/Chrome with an Adobe plug-in OR New MSEdge `111` / `III` with its inbuilt Acrobat Reader replacement for Chromiums Skia one

[image]

Google Docs like Firefox/Mozilla PDF.js is not a fully Adobe scripted PDF reader

[image]

Mozilla/Firefox can transfer the download to any Adobe compatible editor

[image]

Many other browsers that can annotate without JS or AcroScript will have problems with the forms appearance as the boxes seem set to be ALWAYS on top so checkmarks etc. are invisible behind the blank box.

[image]

Better would be to leave the box unfilled

[image]